# How can I resolve JUST hostnames under the VPN's domain on the VPN's resolver, while retaining the default resolver

Tags: dns, vpn, resolution

I have a home network running which uses DNS resolutions on `.lan`, for example my router is `router.lan`.

This network is unfortunately `192.168.1.0/24`. Which means it normally conflicts with whatever public network I'm on. However, when I VPN in to my network my router's tunnel address is `192.168.2.1`. This leaves 192.168.1.1 as the public wifi gateway. Everything works. I can route to the vpn's 192.168.1.0/24 by sending the traffic through the tunnel at `192.168.2.1`.

My question here is on DNS resolution. I use dnsmasq as a resolver on a Linux workstation.

I need either,

- `hostname.lan.vpn` for example to proxy resolution through my VPN to my router at `192.168.2.1`, or I need
- `hostname.lan` to proxying the request to my VPN, **BUT** only when connected to the VPN.

Does anyone else share this concern, and how do they handle it?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that `vpn0` is the name of your VPN tunnel interface, you could configure your `dnsmasq` with:

```
--server=/lan/192.168.2.1@vpn0
```

With this configuration line/option, if the `vpn0` interface exists, `dnsmasq` will forward any queries related to the `lan` domain to 192.168.2.1 through the `vpn0` interface. If that interface does not exist, `dnsmasq` will log a warning and ignore the line - which is exactly what you want when the VPN is not active.

For reverse DNS resolution, you could also add:

```
--rev-server=192.168.1.0/24,192.168.2.1@vpn0
```

This does the same for reverse DNS queries related to IP segment 192.168.1.0/24.

Comment: This doesn't work for me, unless I restart dnsmasq when the interface comes up and down.